# Gendern - grammatisch gesehen Unsinn?

Tags: gender

"Ist das Gendern in der deutschen Sprache morphosyntaktisch fundiert?" 
(Christian Geiselmann)

---

Aufgrund der kontroversen Meinungen bezüglich der Berechtigung meiner Fragetellung nehme ich das Angebot von Christian Geiselmann dankend an, o.g. Formulierung zu nutzen. Der Originaltext der ursprünglichen Frage folgt hier:

Unabhängig der Tatsache, woher nun das Streben nach dem "politisch korrekten Gendern" kommt, möchte ich dieses Phänomen der heutigen Zeit einmal sachlich aus morphosyntaktischer Sicht hinterfragen. In den meisten formalen Texten, egal ob in den Medien oder in wissenschaftlichen Texten, Anschreiben etc. findet heute das Gendern statt - die Allgemeinheit hat dies (ungefragt?) längst übernommen.

Dabei ist es doch aus grammatischer Sicht meines Erachtens gar nicht notwendig.

Nimmt man zum Beispiel einmal das Wort "Lehrer" und vergleicht dies mit dem Wort "Lehrerin".
Betrachtet man nun die Flexionsmorpheme, welche die grammatischen Eigenschaften tragen, stellt man fest, dass das Morphem "-er" in "Lehrer" keineswegs für maskulinum (und demzufolge schon gar nicht für biologisch oder gesellschaftlich männlich) steht.
Das Morphem "-in" dagegen trägt die grammatische Eigenschaft "feminin" in sich und macht das Wort Lehrer (welches zwar an sich maskulin ist) zu einem Femininum.
Betrachtet man nun den Sachverhalt genauer, stellt man fest, dass es gar kein Flexionsmorphem für maskulinum (wie analog "-in") in der deutschen Sprache gibt.

Daher ist für mich die Frage, ob es nicht sinnvoller wäre, statt sämtliche Texte (meiner Meinung nach unnötig) in die Länge zu ziehen, ein Umdenken der Deutschsprecher anzuregen, was die Deckungsgleichheit mit dem grammatischen Geschlecht und dem Gender anbelangt. Da wir feststellen konnten, dass es kein Flexionsmorphem gibt, welches ein Wort in ein maskulin kehrt, für das Femininum aber schon, könnte man hier auch die Ungleichheit und Benachteiligung der Männer ansprechen - was aber quatsch wäre, denn es handelt sich bei dem grammatischen Geschlecht eben nicht um Gender. Demzufolge wäre es einfacher, wenn man unter dem Wort "Lehrer" beide Geschlechter versteht (wie in zahlreichen anderen Sprachen [bspw. dem Englischen]) und, nur wenn man explizit erwähnen möchte, dass es sich ausschließlich um eine weibliche Lehrkraft handelt, kann man den Suffix "-in" verwenden. Oder was machen wir, wenn die "neuen" Gender (divers?!) Einzug finden? Erfinden wir dann neue Suffixe? Und bekommt der Mann dann auch einen?

Comment: *Lies bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor Du diese Frage beantwortest oder einen Kommentar schreibst.* - diese Frage wurde korrekt als *primarily opinion-based* geschlossen.

Comment: Wieso wurde mein Kommentar gelöscht?

Comment: @userunknown: [deshalb](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 6):

*Sprachlich* betrachtet sind biologische oder grammatikalische Geschlechter nicht notwendig. Es gibt viele Sprachen, die weder Sachen in grammatikalische Geschlechter einteilen, noch z.B. bei den Personalpronomen unterscheiden. Finnisch und Ungarisch wären Beispiele aus der nächsten Nachbarschaft. Natürlich kann man in diesen Sprachen zwischen Männer und Frauen bei Bedarf unterscheiden, aber in der Regel ist das ja nicht notwendig. Auch in der deutschen Sprache sind die Unterscheidungen meiner Meinung nach nicht für die Verständigung notwendig und könnten einfach per Konvention von heute auf morgen abgeschafft werden. Es gibt natürlich ganz wenige deutsche Wörter, bei denen das grammatikalische Geschlecht bedeutungsrelevant ist, z.B. der See und die See. Wäre es in der Regel so, hätte Deutsch aber in Mehrzahl nicht eine gemeinsame Form für alle Geschlechter haben können, sondern hätte in Mehrzahl auch unterscheiden müssen.

Ob die Unterscheidung kulturell notwendig ist, ist eine ganz andere Frage. Ich bin gebürtiger Norweger und erst als Erwachsener nach Deutschland gezogen. Interessant finde ich es aber durchaus, dass bei der Gleichberechtigung in Deutschland oft komplett in die entgegengesetzte Richtung gezogen wird verglichen mit Norwegen. Und ich kann ja nebenbei ein Bisschen bös fragen wo es mit der Gleichberechtigung besser geklappt hat? Die Unterscheidung zwischen männlichen und weiblichen Personenbezeichnungen ist nur ein Beispiel dafür. Hier in Deutschland wird die Sprache, wie du schreibst, oft radebrechend vergewaltigt, um alle Gender-Formen mitzunehmen, so dass sich niemand auf die Füße getreten fühlt. In Norwegen war es den Frauen vor 40-50 Jahren wichtig sämtliche weibliche Formen abzuschaffen, weil es für sie ein Teil der Gleichberechtigung war mit den gleichen Titeln und Bezeichnungen angesprochen zu werden wie ihre männlichen Kollegen. Ich kann mich noch an einem Aushang im Lehrerzimmer meiner Schule erinnern, auf dem sowas wie "Bin ich nur eine Lehrerin? Wir sind doch alle Lehrer!" stand.

**Edit:** Es fällt mir noch ein, dass eine solche Sprachwandlung "nach Konvention" in Schweden gerade versucht oder durchgeführt wird. Wie in Norwegen, sind in Schweden auch keine weiblichen Berufsbezeichnungen üblich. Es gibt bei den grammatischen Geschlechtern keine Unterscheidung zwischen männlich und weiblich, aber bei den Personalpronomen wird zwischen han (er) und hon (sie) unterschieden, was auch dort zu Konstruktionen wie "er/sie", "er oder sie" oder "er und sie" führt, wenn das Geschlecht einer besprochenen Person unbekannt oder egal ist. Schon 1966 wurde vorgeschlagen eine geschlechtsneutrale Form "hen" einzuführen in Anlehnung an das (einzige) finnische Personalpronomen "hän", das sowohl "er" als auch "sie" bedeutet. Es war wohl nie gemeint damit "han" und "hon" zu *ersetzen*, aber die neue Form *zusätzlich* anzubieten, wo früher Doppelnennungen sonst notwendig erscheinen. Das Wort wird seit 2012 zumindest gelegentlich in der Presse verwendet. 2015 wurde das Wort in der Wörterliste der Schwedischen Akademie aufgenommen und zum ersten Mal auch in einem Gesetzestext verwendet, allerdings auf Åland, einer autonomen Provinz Finlands, die Schwedisch als Amtssprache nutzt. Im schwedisch-sprachigen Teil Finlands, wo teilweise auch die finnische Form "hän" beigemischt wird, scheint sich das Wort schneller durchzusetzen als in Schweden. In der dritten Staffel von "Die Brücke" (schwedisch/dänische Krimi-Serie) führt es immer wieder zu Verwirrungen, dass Saga Norén, die schwedische Ermittlerin mit Asperger-Syndrom, angefangen hat "hen" zu verwenden. Ich wollte mir eigentlich die deutsche Fassung angucken, nur um zu sehen wie sie das in der Übersetzung übernommen haben. Vermutlich gar nicht, wie die meisten anderen sprachlichen Feinheiten der Serie. Es gibt auch ähnliche Vorschläge in den anderen skandinavischen Sprachen (no: hen, da: høn, is: hán), aber die neuen Wörter finden dort kaum Beachtung.

Comment: Wie heißt das schöne Zitat am Schluss auf Norwegisch?

Comment: Das kommt im Norwegischen auch alles noch. Hierzulande wurden ja schließlich auch zuerst die Friseuse und die Politesse abgeschafft. Und der Lehrling. Die heißen nun Azubi und Azubine. Ob's der Verständigung dient? Jedenfalls nenne ich Politessen immer noch Politessen, weil mir *Parkraumbewirtschafterin* doch etwas unanständig daherkommt.

Comment: @Janka Was du hier ansprichst ist die "Aufwertung" niederwertiger Berufsbezeichnungen durch die Erfindung neuer Begriffe. Die gibt es auch ansatzweise in Norwegen. Das hat aber nichts mit der Abschaffung oder Fortführung geschlechtsspezifischer Bezeichnungen zu tun.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "Er jeg kun en lærerinne? Vi er da alle lærere!". Die weiblichen Berufsbezeichnungen werden in den skandinavischen Sprachen ähnlich gebildet wie hier (no: lærer, lærerinne, sv: lärare, lärarinne, da: lærer, lærerinde) aber kaum noch benutzt.

Comment: @jarnbjo - Danke. Ich drucke es mir aus und hefte es an meine Bürotür zur Sammlung interessanter Sprüche in interessanten europäischen Sprachen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Vermutlich ist der Spruch nicht wortwörtlich richtig, aber inhaltlich schon.

Comment: *Lies bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor Du diese Frage beantwortest oder einen Kommentar schreibst.*

Comment: "Von heute auf morgen per Konvention abschaffen" ist ein Widerspruch in sich.

Answer (score 3):

> Gendern - grammatisch gesehen Unsinn?

Sinn und Unsinn sind sehr subjektive Kategorien. Ist "Gendern" grammatikalisch notwendig? Ganz klar "Nein". Davon unabhängig gibt es Gründe warum es trotzdem genutzt wird.

> Daher ist für mich die Frage, ob es nicht sinnvoller wäre, statt sämtliche Texte (meiner Meinung nach unnötig) in die Länge zu ziehen, ein Umdenken der Deutschsprecher anzuregen, was die Deckungsgleichheit mit dem grammatischen Geschlecht und dem Gender anbelangt. Da wir feststellen konnten, dass es kein Flexionsmorphem gibt, welches ein Wort in ein maskulin kehrt, für das Femininum aber schon, könnte man hier auch die Ungleichheit und Benachteiligung der Männer ansprechen - was aber quatsch wäre, denn es handelt sich bei dem grammatischen Geschlecht eben nicht um Gender.

Grammatikalisch gesehen ist es korrekt das grammatische Geschlecht und Gender unterschiedlich sind. Es ist auch korrekt das viele Deutschsprecher beides zur Zeit gleichwertig verwenden. In wie weit ein Umdenken zurück zur Grammatik stattfinden muss (oder bereits statt findet und die Grammatik angepasst werden sollte) ist ein kontroverses Thema und nicht relevant zur aktuellen Fragestellung.

> Demzufolge wäre es einfacher, wenn man unter dem Wort "Lehrer" beide Geschlechter versteht (wie in zahlreichen anderen Sprachen [bspw. dem Englischen]) und, nur wenn man explizit erwähnen möchte, dass es sich ausschließlich um eine weibliche Lehrkraft handelt, kann man den Suffix "-in" verwenden.

Natürlich wäre es einfacher, aber das vernachlässigt die Gründe warum es überhaupt verkompliziert wurde.

> Oder was machen wir, wenn die "neuen" Gender (divers?!) Einzug finden? Erfinden wir dann neue Suffixe? Und bekommt der Mann dann auch einen?

Das hängt ein bisschen davon ab, welchem Ansatz man folgen möchte. Die deutschsprachige Wikipedia hat einen [Artikel zur gendergerechten Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) der auch verschiedene Formen auflistet, wie man auch mehr als nur männlich oder weiblich abbilden kann.

Comment: Diese Antwort folgt der Prämisse der Fragestellung die Gründe für gendergerechte nicht zu berücksichtigen. Ich persönlich glaube, dass dieser Ansatz nicht korrekt ist. Meine andere Antwort versucht daher die Gründe für gendergerechte Sprache zu berücksichtigen.

Comment: *Lies bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor Du diese Frage beantwortest oder einen Kommentar schreibst.*

Answer (score 1):

Zu Beginn möchte ich die Prämisse der Frage selber in Frage stellen. Natürlich ist es grammatikalisch nicht notwendig gendergerechte Sprache zu haben. Aber da Sprache schon immer mehr war als eine rein syntaktische Angelegenheit ist es sinnvoll sich auch mit der Semantik (beabsichtigt und wahrgenommen) zu beschäftigen.

Beim Beispiel "Lehrer" und "Lehrerin" fällt dies in diesem Zusammenhang direkt auf. Die (grammatikalisch) maskuline Form wird für eine männliche Lehrperson verwendet und die (flektierte) feminine Form für eine weibliche Lehrperson. Diese Korrelation zwischen grammatikalischen und biologischen/sozialen Geschlechts ist, was in der Kritik steht. (Zu einem gewissen Punkt existieren auch kausale Zusammenhänge, wo Bezeichnungen eindeutig Bezug auf das biologische Geschlecht nehmen (z.B. Hausfrau, Putzfrau, Laufbursche, Krankenschwester, Feuerwehrmann))

Ein besonderes Problem für die gendergerechte Sprache stellt das generische Maskulinum dar. Außer historischen Gründen (die sich in der aktuellen Grammatik niedergeschlagen haben), gibt es keinen vernünftigen Grund warum eine generisch maskuline Form verwendet werden soll. Die deutsche Sprache würde genauso gut (oder schlecht) funktionieren fall das generische Maskulinum durch ein anderes grammatikalisches Geschlecht ersetzt wird. In unserem heutigen Sprachgebrauch (mit der Trennung zwischen dem Lehrer (m) und der Lehrerin (w)) wirkt das generische Maskulinum auf einige Leute aus der Zeit gefallen, da es für den unbedarften Betrachter sofort die Assoziation mit dem (biologisch oder sozialem) Mann weckt.

Ist es sinnvoll eine "gegenderte" Version zu nutzen? Grammatikalisch gesehen "Nein", auf einer sozialen Ebene "Ja" (unabhängig von den eigenen Überzeugungen sollte ein respektvoller Umgang mit Rücksichtname auf die Gefühle anderer zum Standard gehören, aber das ist nur meine persönliche Meinung).

> Daher ist für mich die Frage, ob es nicht sinnvoller wäre, statt sämtliche Texte (meiner Meinung nach unnötig) in die Länge zu ziehen, ein Umdenken der Deutschsprecher anzuregen, was die Deckungsgleichheit mit dem grammatischen Geschlecht und dem Gender anbelangt.

Hier stimme ich teilweise zu. Natürlich sollte man die Deutschsprecher zu einem Umdenken über die Deckungsgleichheit zwischen grammatischen Geschlecht und Gender erziehen. Aber auch mit Bezug auf die neue "Sprachrealität" die (abweichend von der aktuellen Grammatik) bereits eine Assoziation zwischen grammatischen und biologisch/sozialem Geschlecht herstellt. Aber dieses Umdenken wird lange Dauern und von vielen Seiten Diskussionen erfordern (und am Ende kann eine andere Grammatik stehen oder ein anderes Sprachverständnis).

> Demzufolge wäre es einfacher, wenn man unter dem Wort "Lehrer" beide Geschlechter versteht (wie in zahlreichen anderen Sprachen [bspw. dem Englischen]) und, nur wenn man explizit erwähnen möchte, dass es sich ausschließlich um eine weibliche Lehrkraft handelt, kann man den Suffix "-in" verwenden.

Im Englischen existiert kein grammatikalisches Geschlecht, daher auch kein Problem mit einem generischen Maskulinum. Und warum sollten Frauen einzeln erwähnt werden? Dies ist die Form der (grammatikalischen) Ungleichbehandlung die von Verfechtern der gendergerechten Sprache angeprangert wird. Als Gedankenexperiment kann man sich vorstellen, dass sämtliche Bezeichnungen ab dem 01.01.2019 im generischen Femininum zu stehen haben. Stellenanzeigen werden dann "eine Lehrerin (w/m)" suchen, wir sprechen von den Leserinnen dieses Beitrags und die Deutsch-Sprecherinnen können dann die abweichende maskuline Form nutzen, wenn sie sich sicher sind, dass in der Gruppe keine einzige weibliche Person enthalten ist (also nur Männer). Wer darin kein Problem sieht (als Mann), den würde ich bitten aus Rücksicht auf alle, die im momentanen Sprachgebrauch mit dem generischen Maskulinum ein Problem sehen, im nächsten Jahr das generische Femininum zu verwenden.

> Oder was machen wir, wenn die "neuen" Gender (divers?!) Einzug finden? Erfinden wir dann neue Suffixe? Und bekommt der Mann dann auch einen?

Es gibt bereits Vorschläge wie man damit umgehen könnte. Die berühmt-berüchtigte -x Endung (X-Form) [(Hier eine andere Frage dazu)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46054/what-is-the-synthetic-ending), oder das Gendersternchen (*) sind einige Vorschläge. Die [deutsche Wikipedia Seite zu gendergerechter Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) enthält weitere Vorschläge.

Wem diese alternativen Schreibweisen zu unübersichtlich werden, der hat immer noch die Möglichkeit des generischen Femininums (diskriminierend gegenüber allen Personen, die sich nicht als weiblich identifizieren) oder des generischen Neutrums.

Zusammengefasst: Es gibt keine grammatikalische Notwendigkeit für gendergerechte Sprache, aber sehr wohl eine soziale. Die deutsche Sprache findet sich an dieser Stelle an einer Veränderung (so dass ein Berufen auf die Grammatik kein besonders wirksames Argument ist, da der tatsächliche Sprachgebrauch bereits davon abgewichen ist). Und es gibt genügend Varianten aus denen man zur Zeit auswählen kann, mit unterschiedlichen Inklusionsstufen (z.B. nur ein Geschlecht, nur binäre Geschlechter, allgemeine Platzhalter für alle Geschlechter) und jede Variante hat ihre Vor- und Nachteile.

Meine persönliche Meinung zum Abschluss: Ich denke wir sollten unsere Energie und Diskussionen eher darauf konzentrieren eine lesbare Variante für die Zukunft zu finden in der sich alle eingeschlossen fühlen, als darüber zu diskutieren warum jene Personen, die sich im Moment ausgeschlossen fühlen, "falsch" (und sei es nur grammatikalisch falsch) liegen und sich bitte schön in der aktuellen Grammatik eingeschlossen fühlen sollen.

Comment: Der gesellschaftlich-soziale Aspekt des Genderns ist hier leider vollkommen off-topic.

Comment: @tofro: Ja und nein. In der Frage wurde natürlich gefragt diesen Aspekt zu ignorieren, aber ich glaube man kann die Frage nicht beantworten wenn man die Gründe für gendergerechte Sprache ignoriert.

Comment: Darum ist auch die Frage (bzw. dieser Aspekt davon) vollkommen off-topic. Die Frage im Titel ("...grammatisch gesehen Unsinn?") wäre on-topic.

Comment: Einverstanden. Ich habe eine weitere Antwort gepostet, wo ich versuche on-topic zu bleiben. Ich bin weiterhin der Meinung, dass es richtig ist gendergerechte Sprache nicht nur rein grammatikalisch einzuordnen, deswegen werde ich diese Antwort nicht löschen

Comment: Wir brauchen dringend genderneutrale Kasussuffixe, und zwar nicht Nullmorphemesondern sichtbare. Außer Männern und Frauen wollen künftig ja alle möglichen Misch- und Neuwesen Lehrer werden. Ich schlage darum vor, wo immer tunlich zur Markierung des genus universalis ein *-(i)x* anzuhängen. Die Stellenanzeige heißt dann: "*Wir suchen zum nächstmöglichen Zeitpunkt einix Lehrix für deutsche Grammatik. Wir bieten ein verständnisvolles Arbeitsumfeld mit sehr aufgeschlossenen Kollegixen und Schülixen. Die Bezahlung richtet sich nach der Qualifikation dix Bewerbix.*"

Comment: Dein Gedankenexperiment, ab  2019 ausschließlich Formen im Femininum zu verwenden, trifft es für mich nicht ganz.
Die deutsche Eigenart, viele Berufsbezeichnungen bspw. im Maskulinum zu verwenden, beruht auf gesprochener und (über Jahrhunderte) akzeptierter Konvention. Daran möchte ich nicht rütteln.
Nehmen wir das Wort "Bedienung" als Berufs-/ oder Personenbezeichnung. Ein Femininum, mit welchem auch ich einst, bei einem Nebenjob, angesprochen wurde und mich (abgesehen davon, dass das Wort auf mich konnotativ leicht abwertend wirkt) als Mann angesprochen gefühlt habe. Oder "Leitung".

Comment: Die "Hausverwaltung", die "Verlagsleitung", die "Bedienung", die "Straßenreinigung", die "Chefetage", die "Reinigung" etc.

Comment: ... all diese Wörter können genderunabhängig Personen(-gruppen) bezeichnen.
Mir ist nicht bekannt, dass man sich hier für eine Spezifizierung des Geschlechts ausgesprochen hat. Dann müsste die deutsche Sprache doch - wenn schon, denn schon - konsequent adaptiert werden, wenn Deckungsgleichheit des grammatischen Geschlechts mit dem Gender angestrebt wird.

Das Mädchen. Das Weibchen. Das Fräulein. Auch diese Wörter müssten "feminisiert" werden.

Es ist sehr viel komplexer, daher mein Gedanke, statt die Sprache zu zerhackstückeln ein antisexistisches, sprachliches Bewusstsein zu schaffen.

Comment: Die Kernaussage in Absatz 2 ist falsch. "Die (grammatikalisch) maskuline Form wird für eine männliche Lehrperson verwendet". Die grammatisch maskuline Form wird für die Funktion verwendet, für männliche wie weibliche Lehrer. Und die Gedankenexperimente mit Sprachumstellung zum 1.1.2019 sind Hirngespinste die nur funktionieren, weil es in der Phantasie so leicht ist die Probleme der realen Welt auszublenden. In Wahrheit liegt keine elegante Reformsprache vor, die sich sprechen lässt und die Chancen hätte ohne Sanktionen übernommen zu werden. Ein großes Problem ist, dass man das Datum und oft …

Comment: … die politische Einstellung des Sprechers/Schreibers kennen muss, um zu wissen, wie der Text interpretiert werden soll. Die Person ist auch eine generische Form oder die Fachkraft, die Koryphäe, das Mitglied. Nur aufgrund beharrlicher Wiederholung fühlen sich Frauen ausgeschlossen. Der Löffel ist auch nicht männlicher als das Messer oder die Gabel. Leher ist nicht männlich, Lehrer ist bereits neutral. Wenn man einen Mann meint, der Lehrer ist, muss man "männlicher Lehrer" sagen, wenn es aus dem Kontext nicht bereits klar ist.

Comment: @userunknown Ein nicht unerheblicher Teil der deutschen Öffentlichkeit benutzt bereits die gegenderte Version der Berufsbezeichnungen. Für viele Leute wäre es befremdlich zu einer Frau zu sagen: "Ach Sie sind der Lehrer meines Kindes" (oder dies als Frau zu hören). Ich stimme durchaus zu, dass eine rückwärtsgewandte komplett syntaktische Analyse diese Nutzung nicht rechtfertigt, sie ist aber Teil der neuen Sprachrealität.

Comment: Mein Gedankenexperiment bewegte sich eher in Richtung der Diskriminierung. Mir ist bewusst das die deutsche Sprache nicht zum Jahreswechsel umgestellt werden kann (und ich würde es auch nicht wollen). Es ist aber durchaus möglich einen radikalen Wechsel zu einem generischen Femininum in einem begrenzten Rahmen (z.B. persönlicher Sprachgebrauch oder siehe auch die Uni Leipzig) durchzuführen und es wird zu absolut keiner Einbüßung von Verständlichkeit (verglichen mit dem generischen Maskulinum) führen.

Comment: @Hinterfrager Für die gendergerechte Sprache geht es eben darum an den alten Konventionen zu rütteln. Einige rütteln sachte (Lehrer und Lehrerin), andere etwas stärker (LehrerIn) und einige versuchen diese Konventionen direkt abzuschütteln (Lehr-x, Lehrx). Und natürlich fordert die gendergerechte Sprache nicht bei den Berufsbezeichnungen aufzuhören. Es wird nur am lautesten diskutiert, da es mit der Gleichberechtigung in der Arbeitswelt einhergeht.
In wie weit die reine Syntax "anti-sexistisch" oder "sexistisch" ist, hängt vom Auge des Betrachters ab (daher auch mein Gedankenexperiment).

Comment: Außerdem glaube ich, dass Sprache sich ändert und der Zug um zu den ursprünglichen Bedeutungen zurück zu kehren bereits abgefahren ist. Ähnlich wie mit vielen Sprachänderungen hat sich hier etwas eingebürgert und keine akademische Diskussion wird es jemals wieder einfangen können. In diesem Sinne denke ich dass ein Dagegenankämpfen sinnlos ist und man lieber mit gutem (und möglicherweise gut verständlichem) Beispiel vorangehen sollte um die Sprache von morgen zu gestalten (falls so etwas überhaupt möglich ist).

Comment: @QueensKnight: Sie meinen in der direkten Ansprache sei vor den frühen 80ern, als mit Senta Trömmel-Plötz und Luise Pusch, letztere später unrühmlich bekannt geworden mit einer Quotenforderung für Cockpits, damit depressive Piloten nicht mehr mit Passagierflugzeugen in ein Voralpenmassiv stürzen, die  deutschsprachige Variante geschlechtsdominierter Sprache aus der Taufe gehoben wurde eine Lehrerin im Singular als Lehrer angesprochen worden? Haben Sie schon mal einen Schwarz-Weiß-Film geschaut? Lesen Sie mal Goethe, Kafka, Mann unter diesem Gesichtspunkt. Nicht Sprach-, maximal Schreibrealität

Comment: 2. Welche Diskriminierung? Es gibt in der dt. Sprache nur eine Hervorhebung mittels Endung für Frauen. Wenn da jmd. diskriminiert wird, dann Männer. "Lehrer" bezeichnet einen Beruf, keine sexuelle Funktion. Dass man den Genus nach den Geschlechtern männlich/weiblich genannt hat - und übrigens sächlich, obwohl die meisten Sachen dann wieder männlich oder weiblich sind, die Oberkategorie Sache per se wieder weiblich, das ist eigentlich die einzige Kuriosität die man lernen muss, um zu begreifen, dass hier keine Diskriminierung vorliegt. Männer haben nix davon. Der Hammer, die Zange.

Comment: Im ganz engen Bereich formaler Papiere wird diese unsinnige Sprachgymnastik praktiziert. Es gibt sehr viel mehr Schriften, die nicht nach diesen ausgedachten Regeln verfasst werden als umgekehrt. Selbst die Taz, die eine zeitlang so abgefasst wurde, ist davon wieder abgekommen. Reden tut überhaupt niemand so, außer Speakerinnen auf feministischen Tagungen, wo es der Selbstmarkierung dient. Im Alltag hält es keiner durch, weil es nicht durchzuhalten ist. Im Gegensatz zur sonstigen Sprache, wo die Regeln aus dieser abgeleitet sind, wird hier umgekehrt versucht, die Sprache in Regeln zu zwingen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85901/discussion-between-user-unknown-and-queensknight).