# Warum gendert man nicht einfach beim Singular?

Tags: gender-neutrality

Anstatt mit ***, -*innen*, anderen Formulierungen usw. zu gendern, warum ändert man nicht einfach den männlichen Singular?

Also zum Beispiel mit der Endung -un:

- Die Schülerin (Singular, weiblich)
- Der Schülerun (Singular, männlich)
- Der Schüler   (Singular, geschlechtsneutral)
- Die Schülerunnen (Plural, männliche Gruppe)
- Die Schülerinnen (Plural, weibliche Gruppe)
- Die Schüler      (Plural, geschlechtsneutral)

Wäre das nicht viel, viel einfacherer?

> *Lies bitte [unsere Regeln für Fragen über gendergerechte Sprache u. Ä.](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1340), bevor Du diese Frage beantwortest oder einen Kommentar schreibst.*

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47947/gendern-grammatisch-gesehen-unsinn/47956#47956 is good read

Comment: Siehe auch: [Vorschläge für männliche Movierung](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25093/2594)

Comment: Das ist keine Frage. Das ist ein Diskussionsvorschlag. Nicht, dass Diskussionen übers Gendern unerwünscht wären, sie passen nur einfach nicht hierher.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt zwei Motivationen gegenderte Sprache zu verwenden:

a) Bei direkter Ansprache die Inklusion: Jede Person soll angesprochen werden egal wie diese sich selbst sehen und sich niemand ausgelassen oder der Wortwahl wegen nicht angesprochen fühlen.

b) [Durchbrechen von Cliches](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1908156116): Eine (ggf. auch) unbewusste Bevorzugung oder Konnotation des Gesagten bezüglich des einen oder anderen Geschlechts soll vermieden werden. Stereotypen sollen gebrochen werden.

Beides kann mit Deinem Vorschlag nur erreicht werden, wenn die geschlechtsneutrale Variante noch nicht gedanklich mit der verwendeten grammatikalischen Form bewusst oder unbewusst assoziert ist. Das ist aber bei "der Schüler" der Fall: es bezeichnet z.Z. entweder einen männlichen Schüler oder allgemein einen Schüler. Die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass das mentale Bild des Wortes "Schüler" eher ein Junge ist als ein Mädchen, ist deshalb größer. Wird die Klasse damit direkt angesprochen, so kann jedes Mädchen durchaus auch zur Recht behaupten, damit nicht angesprochen zu sein - denn man hätte dann ja auch Schülerin sagen können.

Ein anderes Beispiel, wo der gedankliche Bias vielleicht noch besser funktioniert: denk an eine Mechanikwerkstatt zur Metallbearbeitung mit CNC-Fräsen, Sägen, Bohrern etc. Welches mentale Bild hast Du als aller erstes ohne nachzudenken beim Wort "Werkstattleiter" vor Augen?

> Ist es eher ein (älterer) Mann? Oder die junge engagierte Meisterin, die die Mechanikwerkstatt leitet?

In Abwesenheit einer Sprachvergangenheit ließe sich wunderbar ein solches System designen, meinetwegen gerne wie von Dir vorgeschlagen, weil es relativ logisch die Begriffe bildet. Sprache hat aber Historie und es gibt Sprachgebrauch, d.h. man fängt nicht bei Null an. Deshalb muss man, wenn man gendern will, die geschlechtsneutrale Form so wählen, dass sie noch nicht mit einem gedanklichen Bias belegt ist. Schweden hat das mit der Einführung des geschlechtsneutralen Pronomen 'hen' 2015 geschafft.

Comment: Darüber hinaus, was @userunknown schon gesagt hat, würde ich noch einwenden, daß weibliche Werkstattleiter im Vergleich zu männlichen selten sind - das ist Fakt. Wer das Wort "Omelett" hört, denkt auch zuerst an etwas, das aus Hühner- und nicht aus Wachteleiern gemacht wurde - einfach, weil ersteres deutlich häufiger als zweiteres ist.

Comment: @userunknown Ich lösche deine Kommentare, weil sie unfreundlich sind und damit gegen den Code of Conduct dieser Seite verstoßen. Achte bitte in Zukunft darauf, deine Posts so zu formulieren, dass der Respekt allen hier gegenüber stets gewahrt bleibt.